# in kendo multiple sub-grids configuration, names are not correctely affected

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, propertygrid, subgrid

I have a main Kendo grid and a template definition for a sub grid. The sub-grid name is composed with an ID of the main grid, like that ;

```
.Name("Orders_#=EmployeeID#")
```

I try to access to the sub-grid whith jquery :

```
        var grid = $("#Orders_"  +  EmployeeID.tostring()).data("kendoGrid");
```

The variable grid is undefined. It seems that the Name property of the sub-grid "Orders_#=EmployeeID#" is not well interpreted. Looking at the web page source, I do not find the combined name of the grid but a bad interpreted id  "Orders_#=EmployeeID#".

Is it a known bug ?

Comment: How are you adding this/these sub grids onto the page? Can you provide a bit more detail about your grid setup

Answer (score 0):

i am not preety much sure about my answer but i think this may help you

try escaping the hash tags in the EmployeeID decleration as specified below

```
.Name("Orders_\#=EmployeeID\#")
```